# Replacement for build-announcements on Gradle 6.X

Tags: gradle, plugins

I am looking for a replacement to build-announcements that works on Gradle 6.X.
It is part of my flow to leave the unit tests running continuously in the background and check it only when I see a failure pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Find a suitable community plugin replacement for sending out notifications in the [Gradle plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) as specified [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#the_announce_and_build_announcements_plugins_have_been_removed).
2. Maintain the `announce` and `build-announcements` plugins yourself by copying the [source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/v5.6.4/subprojects/announce/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/announce) into your project.

Comment: Creating a fork and maintain is the best option but the code is extremely interdependent and  hard to separate. Worth the effort, I will get there eventually.
There was no plugin showing up on search that would provide similar functionality.